# What are some good options for Black Walnut resistant plants?

Tags: plant-health

So here's the situation: I moved into a house with a monstrous, large black walnut tree.  My wife planted her expensive winterized roses. But they died.  Evidently the black walnut tree killed them off.  The tree is cut down now. But I supposed we'll have to wait for the root system to die off over the the years to come. So this, then, is my question:

- What are some good options for plants that might resist the black walnut?
- As a side question, are there any plants that repel squirrels too?

Comment: I am reading it as an AND condition, not an OR. So not voting to close.

Comment: Black walnut trees used to be worth a fortune ; is it still very valuable ?

Comment: Yeah, it's hundreds of years old. the guys who took it will mill it into something really nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Search term: **juglone tolerant plants** (there are many - in my opinion too many to list here, and you can pick and choose ones that appeal to you, rather than me picking and choosing ones that appeal to me.)
- Good luck with that. They've been getting walnuts for a long time, right there. Heck, they buried a lot, most likely. They will be around.

Comment: By "search term" do you mean within SE, or on google?

Comment: In your search engine or location of choice.

Answer (score 1):

As for your  Squirrel problem, I don't know of any I don't know of any plans that ward off squirrels but I do know that good combination of hot pepper ground pepper sprinkled on the ground will keep squirrels away.

Comment: Hmmmm, I might have to try that.

Comment: We tried the *Hot pepper keeps squirrels from eating birdseed* myth. Apparently our squirrels don't mind spicy, so... I consider it a myth.

Comment: No, pepper doesn't keep squirrels away.  It doesn't keep anything away that I can tell.